# OpenCV gaussianblur making image loose colors

Tags: python, opencv, gaussianblur

I am applying OpenCV's GaussianBlur on an image. Resulting image looks to lack the colors original image has.

My code:

```
originalImage = cv2.imread('path to original image',0)
blurredImage = cv2.GaussianBlur(originalImage,(15,15),0)
cv2.imwrite('path to save the new image', blurredImage)
```

Original image:
[image]
New image:
[image]
Is this correct behaviour?I want to retain the color details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the line reading the image as:

```
originalImage = cv2.imread('path to original image',0)
```

The param `0` in the `cv2.imread()` instructs the library to read grayscale image irrespective of the original image configuration. To fix this you can call `cv2.imread()` with no params as:

```
originalImage = cv2.imread('path to original image')
```

This command instructs the library to read the image in `BGR` config.

But if you want to read the image in the exact same format as it is, then you may need to call:

```
originalImage = cv2.imread('path to original image', -1)
```

You may refer to `cv2.imread()` [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for input.